# Changing the order of GUI-elements inside Arduino ESP-Dash-library

Tags: esp32, json

I'm trying to add a new item "index" to GUI-elements that are created by using ArduinoJSON and the Vue.js-framework inside the ESP-Dash-library.

The library creates GUI-elements like buttons, sliders etc. and provides easy to program call-back-procdures to make the microcontroller interact with the user-input from the website.

The code as it is iterates through all defined GUI-elements and creates the HTML-code. First all temperture-showing elements then all humidity elements, then all sliders etc...

This means the sequence and the position of the GUI-elements can't be defined by the programmer.

The new functionality I want to achieve is that the programmer can define the sequence and position of all GUI-elements on the website.

This means a new item like "index" must be added and the HTML-creation-code must be changed to another kind of iteration through the GUI-elements.

Now I'm very lost on where to look into all the Arduino- or the javascript-code  to find that place where the iteration must be changed.

Here is the link to the GiPo https://github.com/ayushsharma82/ESP-DASH

and especially to the app.vue javascript https://github.com/ayushsharma82/ESP-DASH/blob/master/vue-frontend/src/App.vue

If this kind of question is inapropriate please drop a few words what is wrong.
And then add a link to "how to post good questions"

best regards Stefan